# API to get price of Binance Smart Chain token on PancakeSwap

Tags: binance-smart-chain

I have address of a token and I need to get its price in BUSD or BNB.
It's not a problem to use paid API, if there is no other way. This token may not be listed on popular listings so it would be nice to get price somehow directly from PancakeSwap.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to get it directly from PancakeSwap

```
https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3
```

Comment: doesn't work with all tokens, try to use it with yCln 0x0997E2905CDa889Db78D030599989e3121453B6F

Comment: + it's not live data, it is refreshed hourly. That's why scraping is the only solution ;) Would require an headless chromium for doing so

Comment: @TheDayIsDone This just stopped working... any idea? I see `{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Network error: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0"}}`

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine used Moralis.
https://docs.moralis.io/introduction/readme
https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/web3-api/token#gettokenprice

Maybe you can already do something with the documentation, I have otherwise asked my colleague for example code

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/erc20/0x42F6f551ae042cBe50C739158b4f0CAC0Edb9096/price?chain=bsc&exchange=PancakeSwapv2' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-API-Key: MY-API-KEY'
```

Result:

```
{
  "nativePrice": {
    "value": "8409770570506626",
    "decimals": 18,
    "name": "Ether",
    "symbol": "ETH"
  },
  "usdPrice": 19.722370676,
  "exchangeAddress": "0x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984",
  "exchangeName": "Uniswap v3"
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: Thank you @Mendoza. Next thing I would need is to fetch the price at a certain date, if possible.

Comment: @Tulleb A direct API query is not possible as far as I know, but you can query the price if you specify the parameter `to_block` to get the price for a specific date
, But I don't know how to find the right block for the date, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using React you can try the following package: [react-pancakeswap-token-price](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pancakeswap-token-price)

Answer (score -2):

you can **scrape** charts.bogged.finance or poocoin.app