# Get price of token from pancakeswap (python) no longer working

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, price, pancakeswap

This URL used to work nicely to get a coins price from pancakeswap:

```
https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3
```

...but it appears to no longer work.

I assume that pancakeswap has changed their code, and stack overflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903944/api-to-get-price-of-binance-smart-chain-token-on-pancakeswap) are outdated. So how do I get the price of a coin from pancakeswap using python?

Comment: That is not a line of code. It's a URL

Comment: Have you looked at the API documentation?

Comment: @pingu I have updated the words 'line of code' to read 'url'

Comment: @MattDMo I've checked the api but when I use their example I get the response "Network error: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0" Someone answered the question so I'll keep it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PancakeSwap API is dead and the repo is archived.

Read: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/issues

Find another source of WebSockets until they fix this (I don't know if it's temporally either)

Comment: Thank you for this, I was wondering what was going wrong. Thank you :)